# Data Types Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, math, gdb

> **Exact Duplicate:**
>   [Issue with float and double data types in objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024913/issue-with-float-and-double-data-types-in-objective-c)

[Ironically, to find the duplicate questions you need to know the answer.]

Comment: To quote from the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) on the subject, "Some numbers (e.g., 1/3 and 0.1) cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point no matter what the precision."

Comment: This is a common question having more to do with the general computer science topic of floating point representation than objective c.  I'll tag one of the many duplicate questions.

Comment: As for why `NSLog` prints differently than `gdb`, a 32-bit floating point number is good for about 7 digits of precision.  So it appears that perhaps `NSLog` is truncating after the seventh digit to give a more meaningful output, while `gdb` is showing the exact value that is stored in your variable without taking precision into account.  Interestingly, I think one could argue that both behaviors are correct in their particular context.

Comment: Are there implications for Javascript and Java of this, or is the problem "virtualized away"?

Comment: @Yar Same issue for C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, etc, etc

Comment: @PengOne which is basically no issue, unless you happen to be dealing with numbers that require greater than the precision provided by your data type, right?

Comment: @Yar Not at all. It means using `==` with `float`s can get you into trouble. They may be the same algebraically, but if they were arrived at in different ways, they may not appear exactly equal. I've been vexed by this issue before.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985601/strange-result-of-division-in-c and many others.

Comment: Thanks @PeterDeWeese I had learned, forgotten and remembered this topic here. It is indeed basic.

Answer (score 3):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

If it cannot be expressed in base `2`, it will not be precise. See also [floating point inaccuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Answer (score 0):

0.1 is a 'repeating decimal' in binary (0.0001100110011...) so the representation of 0.1 is inexact. NSLog is likely rounding or truncating the output.

Comment: Repeating *decimal* in *binary*?  (I know what you meant, that's just an odd way of saying it.()

Comment: Calling it a 'repeating binary in binary' sounded worse. Is there a standard way to refer to a number with a repeating fractional portion in other bases?

Comment: "a number with a repeating fractional portion"?  But I admit that "repeating decimal" get the idea across clearly.

Comment: I think "repeating decimal" is the correct term, regardless of the base.  In this case "decimal" refers to "the stuff that comes after the decimal point" and not to the numbers base.  Perhaps "binary repeating decimal" is the most concise descriptor?