# How to avoid rounding off the float value when called from sqlite

Tags: ios, sqlite, nsnumber

I am using the following statement to get a float value from table:

```
NSNumber *f = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(double)sqlite3_column_double(statement, 0)];
```

The value in the database is 23.679999999 but I am getting 23.68. I tried numberWithFloat but i got the same result. 
Can anyone tell me how to get the value without rounding off?

Comment: What's the data type of the field in sqlite?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5024913/comparing-float-and-double-data-types-in-objective-c

Comment: Get the field as text and see what it really is.  (You can use the command line `sqlite3` command to do this.)  Then convert that text value to double and see what you get.  And keep in mind that if you print a double with `%f` you get a rounded value.

Comment: the actual text is "1523.6799999999998"

Comment: How are you seeing the 23.68 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSNumber`-wrapped-`double` is not a suitable data type for storing decimal values when all digits must be preserved exactly. Use [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/) instead:

```
unsigned char *c = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
NSNumber *f = nil;
if (c) {
    NSString *numStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:c];
    f = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:numStr];
}
```

This should preserve all significant digits available in your text representation, as long as you use the native value. Converting to `float` or `double` may result in rounding due to differences in representation.